# "specializations don’t participate in overloading"

Tags: c++, templates

What does it really mean by ***"Specialization of function templates Don't take part in overload resolution. Only base templates are considered"***

I wrote a simple template function with its specialized verion and could see that specialized was called:

```
// Base template
template <typename T>
T max(T a, T b) {
    std::cout << "Base Template" << std::endl;
    return (a>b) ? a : b;
}

// Specialization for int
template<>
int max<int>(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << "int specialization" << std::endl;
    return (a>b) ? a : b;
}
max(2,3);// prints "int specialization"
```

Looking at other StackOverflow related to this concept, i found another post in which to prove that specializations don't take part in overloading he showed the following example in which the specialized version was not called and i am still not sure why it was not called. But apart from that, in this example, the argument doesn't have a variable name still there is no compile or runtime error for the part `(char const* const&)`

```
template<typename T>
void f(T const&)
{
        std::cout<<std::endl<<"Base Template for f() called\n";
}

template<>
void f<char const * const &>(char const* const&)
{
        std::cout<<std::endl<<"Specialized f() for char const* called\n";
}
f("Hello") //prints "Base Template for f() called"
```

In all, i am still trying to figure out the meaning of "Specialization of function templates Don't take part in overload resolution. Only base templates are considered", if someone could explain with an example(and why Base Template was called in second example).
And secondly, why the program compiled and ran fine without variable name in second example.

Comment: Template specialization is not the same as overloading. Overloading would be if you have a *non* template function `int max(int a, int b);`.

Comment: Can you link the other post?

Comment: Yes, a non templated function would be given preference over a templated specialized version. Is that it? Is that the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: If you can spare some time, you may find useful to watch [this talk by Walter E. Brown about function templates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIDEjY5ywqU).

Comment: @Bob__ Sure. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try `max(5, 7.0)`, you'll get an error even though a `double` is convertible to an `int`. So the `int` specialisation of `max` doesn't participate in overload resolution.

```
template <typename T>
T max(T a, T b);

template <>
int max(int a, int b);

max(5, 7.0); // compiler error (no matching function)
```

However, if you had used a regular function instead of a template specialisation, you'd get the expected behaviour.

```
template <typename T>
T max(T a, T b);

int max(int a, int b);

max(5, 7.0); // this is fine
```

When the compiler considers the argument types `(int, double)`, it looks for functions in the following order (it's a little more complicated than this with ADL and other details):

- exactly matching functions (e.g. `max(int, double)`. So `max(int, int)` won't be considered at this stage)
- matching function templates (e.g. `max(T, U)`. So `max(T, T)` won't be considered because `T` can't be both `int` and `double`)
- functions with compatible arguments (e.g. `max(int, int)` since `double` is implicitly convertible to `int`)

Notice that I didn't mention function template specialisations. If a matching function template is found, an exactly matching specialisation will be used (so if you specialised for `double`s but you call with `int`s that specialisation won't be used), otherwise the base template will be used.

For a better explanation, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

Comment: Agreed. But, the confusion is more than that which is why i provided second exmaple. In that, wasn't it appropriate to call the specialized version for `char const * const&` ?   You can try a `template<typename T>max(T a)` with a specialized `tempalte<>max(int a)` and you will always see that specialized is called. Now just change the `int` to `int&` and you will see Base template instead of specialized is getting called. Not sure why

Comment: Also, regarding the second question - where there is no variable name, how can it get compiled and run.

Comment: If you specialise for `int &` and call with an `int` then that is not an exact match for the specialisation (as I stated in the second to last paragraph) so the base template will be used.

Comment: What do you mean "no variable name"? There are no variables here.

Comment: No, i am saying specialize with `int&` and call with `int&` itself.

Comment: By no variable name i meant shouldn't the function be `void f(T const& i)` which has a var `i`   instead of `void f(T const&)` which doesn't have any name but just the type

Comment: Oh I see your confusion. The type of `"hello"` is not `const char *`. It is `const char [6]`. This is not an exact match for the specialisation so the base template is used.

Comment: Oh Yes. What about the compilation being successful inspite of variable being absent

Comment: If you don't use a function parameter, you don't need to mention its name. BTW, to specialise `f` you can use `template<> void f(char const (&)[6])` so `f("hello")` will choose the specialisation.