# In the function template, char * arguments cannot match explicit specialization const char * parameters

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

IN the book C++ Primer Plus I see a form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24NTx.jpg)

and when I write my code below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
T maxn(T arr[],int n);

template<>
const char*  maxn<const char* >(const char*arr[] ,int n);

template<>
char*  maxn<char* >(char*arr[] ,int n);

int main()
{   
    int arr1[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    double arr2[4]={1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4};
    char* arr3[5]={
        "a",
        "hijkl",
        "def",
        "bc",
        "lmno",
    };
    
    cout << maxn(arr3,4) << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
template<typename T>            //template A  general template
T maxn(T arr[],int n)
{
    T max=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    max = max > arr[i]?max:arr[i];
    return max;
}

template<>             //template B   explicit specialization  with const
const char*  maxn<const char* >(const char* arr[] ,int n)  
{                                                      
    const char*  pm=arr[0];                           
                                                       
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(strlen(pm)<strlen(arr[i]))
        pm=arr[i];
    }
    return pm;
}

template<>      //Template C  explicit specialization  without const
char*  maxn<char* >(char* arr[] ,int n)
{   
    char*  pm=arr[0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(strlen(pm)<strlen(arr[i]))
        pm=arr[i];
    }
    return pm;
}
```

If template a and template c are removed, the actual parameter char * will not be assigned to the const char parameter of template b, and an error message will be reported:
Undefined reference to `char maxn<char *>(char * *, int)`, I understand its meaning. It says that I did not define a template like `char * maxn<char *>(char * *, int)` but does not the book say that type can be converted to const type? Why not convert the `char*` here to `const char*`?

I think template B should be used instead error.

Comment: `char* arr3[5]` is wrong to begin with. Your compiler should be complaining, because literal strings (like for example `"a"`) are *constant*. You need `const char*` for such strings. And with that said, you should almost *never* need `char*` (or `const char*`) for strings, use `std::string` for all your strings. And `std::array` for all your arrays (alternatively `std::vector`).

Comment: *"Why not convert the `char*` here to `const char*`?"* -- Why should a conversion be done? Didn't you explicitly declare that there is a version of `maxn` that takes a `char* []` parameter? A function that requires no conversions is a better match than one that requires a conversion -- why do you expect the compiler to pick an inferior match?

Comment: Basically, ["specializations don’t participate in overloading/overload resolution"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054887/specializations-don-t-participate-in-overloading). See the example given in the above post: `template <typename T>T max(T a, T b); template <>int max(int a, int b); max(5, 7.0); // compiler error (no matching function)`